# Pass data to component in livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

This is my welcome.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<x-frontpage></x-frontpage>
@endsection
```

This is my frontpage.blade.php

```
<h1 class="text-center">{{ $product->name }}</h1>
```

This is my error

```
$product is not passed to welcome.blade.php
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add a props to your `x-frontpage` blade component, otherwise it wouldn't be able to receive it.

Here's an example:

```
<!-- frontpage.blade.php -->

@props(['product'])

<h1 class="text-center">{{ $product->name }}</h1>
```

```
<!-- welcome.blade.php -->

@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<x-frontpage :product="$product"></x-frontpage>
@endsection
```

Also make sure your `welcome.blade.php` has the `$product` variable.

Here are more resources:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/rendering-components#render-method